# Paging a webgrid by Model and Count

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, grid, pagination, webgrid

I've been developing an asp.net mvc 3 application and I'm using webgrid to show tabular data in my view. My question is, how can I page some data by counting how many records I have in the database and show the pager of webgrid in my grid's footer? For example, in my repository I have:

```
public PagedList<Acesso> ObterAcessos(long idPessoa, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
{
    return new PagedList<Acesso>
               {
                   PageIndex = pageIndex,
                   PageSize = pageSize,
                   Total = Session.QueryOver<Acesso>().Where(acesso => acesso.Pessoa.Id == idPessoa).FutureRowCount(),
                   List = Session.QueryOver<Acesso>()
                       .Where(acesso => acesso.Pessoa.Id == idPessoa)
                       .OrderBy(acesso => acesso.DataInicio).Desc
                       .Take(pageSize).Skip((pageIndex - 1)*pageSize)
                       .Future<Acesso>()
               };
}
```

My controller:

```
public ActionResult Acessos(int page = 1)
{
   // 30 records per page
   return View(_rep.ObterAcessos(SecurityHelper.User.Id, page, 30));
}
```

My View:

```
@model PagedList<Acesso>    
@{
        ViewBag.Title = "Acessos";
        var grid = new WebGrid(rowsPerPage: Model.PageSize, canSort: false, ajaxUpdateContainerId: "grid");
        // set the rowCount by Total property and the List property
        grid.Bind(rowCount: Model.Total, source: Model.List);
    }

        <h2>Acessos</h2>

        @grid.GetHtml(htmlAttributes: new { id="grid", style="width:700px;" },
            mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
            tableStyle: "grid", rowStyle: "gridrow", alternatingRowStyle: "gridrow_alternate",
            columns: grid.Columns(
                    grid.Column("DataInicio", "Data de Inicio", item => item.DataInicio.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")), 
                    grid.Column("IP", "IP"))
            )
```

The data comes right, the counting and the list is right, but when I run this code, it doesn't page data, it shows only the first page and the pager of webgrid isn't shown in my view. Is there any property I can set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are doing the paging in your model, you should add:

```
autoSortAndPage: false
```

to your grid.Bind() so it reads:

```
grid.Bind(rowCount: Model.Total, source: Model.List, autoSortAndPage: false);
```

That should enable the paging in the footer the way you want it.